# Should I mutex lock a single variable?

Tags: c, embedded

If a single 32-bit variable is shared between multiple threads, should I put a mutex lock around the variable?  For example, suppose 1 thread writes to a 32-bit counter and a 2nd thread reads it.  Is there any chance the 2nd thread could read a corrupted value?

I'm working on a 32-bit ARM embedded system.  The compiler always seems to align 32-bit variables so they can be read or written with a single instruction.  If the 32-bit variable was not aligned, then the read or write would be broken down into multiple instructions and the 2nd thread could read a corrupted value.

Does the answer to this question change if I move to a multiple-core system in the future and the variable is shared between cores?  (assuming a shared cache between cores)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about races, or are you just concerned about tearing?

Comment: Once you have satisfied yourself that tearing doesn't happen, remember not to write `i++`, or `i+=j` without a mutex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about tearing - I didn't know that's what it was called.  I'm mainly just wondering what is "standard" and/or what is "good practice" to avoid both tearing and race conditions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mutex protects you from more than just tearing - for example some ARM implementations use out-of-order execution, and a mutex will include memory (and compiler) barriers that may be necessary for your algorithm's correctness.

It is safer to include the mutex, then figure out a way to optimise it later if it shows as a performance problem.

Note also that if your compiler is GCC-based, you may have access to the [GCC atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the details.  Reading http://www.usenix.org/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf convinced me you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

If all the writing is done from one thread (i.e. other threads are only reading), then no you don't need a mutex. If more than one thread *may* be writing, then you do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need mutex.
On 32-bit ARM, single write or read is an atomic operation. (regardless of the number of cores)
Of course, you should declare that variable as volatile.

Comment: For my simple case above I think this makes sense.  However, David Heffernan's comment about tearing led me to http://www.usenix.org/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf.  That paper makes me much more nervous about benign data races and how "volatile" may not be a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

On a 32-bit system, reads and writes of 32-bit vars are atomic.  However, it depends what else you are doing with the variable.  E.g. if you maniputale it somehow (e.g. add a value), then this requires a read, manipulation and write. If the CPU and compiler do not support an atomic operation for this, then you will need to use a mutex to protect this multi-operation sequence.

There are other, lock-free techniques which can reduce the need for mutexes.

Comment: do cpus with non-atomic "move" operation exist? I believed each machine instruction that updates the value of a memory location would be atomic and all should care of is just the fact that one thread can read an old value instead of the updated one (in the case of one thread writing, the other only reading, of course)

Comment: @ShinTakezou - ARM will generate a non-atomic read/write if a 32-bit variable is not aligned.  (i.e., it will do 4 byte loads instead of a word load to avoid an unaligned access exception)

Comment: ARM or the compiler? I suppose it is up to the compiler to generate correct code; and since the compiler "knows" it is indeed generating 4 instructions instead of one for a single write, it could put "barriers" in order to make the whole write atomic and to avoid C programmer to have to worry about details of the hardware the source is compiled for (maybe there must be an option to disable these barriers, but to me they should be added by default, if it is possible of course, and I suppose it should be)

Comment: Sorry - I meant the compiler.  For example, on an ARM system GCC will generate something like the following assembly for an aligned 32-bit load: `ldr     r0, [r0, #7]` and something like the following for an unaligned 32-bit load: `ldrb    r2, [r0, #8]
ldrb    r3, [r0, #7]
ldrb    r1, [r0, #9]
orr     r3, r3, r2, lsl #8
ldrb    r2, [r0, #10]
orr     r3, r3, r1, lsl #16
orrs    r2, r3, r2, lsl #24`.  GCC doesn't add any kind of lock around this code for you.